# Boost.Test check if structs are equals

Tags: c++, boost, boost.test

I'm new on Boost.Test on Visual Studio 2017.

I'm trying to test a method with the following Test:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE astroTimeTests
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include "../../AstroTime/Convert.h"

struct TestFixture
{
    Convert convert_instance;

    TestFixture()
        : convert_instance()
    {}

    ~TestFixture() = default;
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(TestConvert, TestFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(julianToGreenWichCase)
{
    // http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm
    tm day1 = { 12, 28, 16, 2, 10, 119, 0, 0, 0};
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(day1, convert_instance.JulianToGreenWich(2458790.18625f));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

`JulianToGreenWich` returns a `tm` struct from `ctime`.

But I'm doing something wrong, because I get the following errors:

> Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const Left' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> Error C2338   Type has to implement operator<< to be printable
>
> Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How can I test if both values, `day1` and the result of `JulianToGreenWich` are equal?

Comment: I don't have experience with Boost.Test, but my guess is nothing implements `bool operator == (const tm &, const tm&)`.  Try writing that function and see if you get further.

Comment: @StephenNewell Where do I have to implement that function? Thanks.

Comment: I have found where to add them (`operator ==` and `operator <<`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have fixed this error:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE astroTimeTests
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include "../../AstroTime/Convert.h"

struct TestFixture
{
    Convert convert_instance;

    TestFixture()
        : convert_instance()
    {}

    ~TestFixture() = default;
};

bool operator ==(tm const &left, tm const &right)
{
    return(
           left.tm_sec == right.tm_sec
        && left.tm_min == right.tm_min
        && left.tm_hour == right.tm_hour
        && left.tm_mday == right.tm_mday
        && left.tm_mon == right.tm_mon
        && left.tm_year == right.tm_year);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const tm& dt)
{
    os << dt.tm_hour << " " << dt.tm_min << " " << dt.tm_sec << ", "
       << dt.tm_mday << " " << dt.tm_mon << " " << (1900 + dt.tm_year) << std::endl;

    return os;
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(TestConvert, TestFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(julianToGreenWichCase)
{
    // http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm
    tm day1 = { 12, 28, 16, 2, 10, 119, 0, 0, 0};
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(day1, convert_instance.JulianToGreenWich(2458790.18625f));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```